# Lower bound for cumulative density function

Tags: calculus, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a task that says to determine the variance of the continuous random variable. This part of the task is easy, but the part i'm stuck at is the boundaries of the integral for determining the variance as seen here.
[Formula for mean and variance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4keY.png)
The task is described in this picture,
[Task description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEAEq.png)

I tried solving the mean and the variance with the lower bound as $\infty$, but it wasn't correct. And later on I only heard that the lower bound is -1 and got no explanation for that. But why is it -1? Why not 0? Should I just assume that because we don't have a specific lower bound, that I should just take my upper bound and make it negative?
I hope you guys can help me with understanding this.

Comment: The lower bound is -1 because $f(x)=0$ if $x<-1$.

Comment: Yes but why not set the bound to -2 or -3 for that matter?

Comment: Because outside [-1,1] the PDF is zero and any integral with respect to that PDF is zero.